# Chrome extension - Detect URL and execute an application

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I know that with a basic chrome extension we can select domains where our extension will work (`<all_urls>`), but is this possible to execute an application ( internal ) when the user visit a specific domain?

I looked previously and saw "Native Messaging". ( I'm currently studying arithmetics ) I want my extension to open automaticly calc.exe when I'm on my working lab's website.

I already did this:

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Mon extension",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "background": {
        "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Ouvrir la calculatrice"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "nativeMessaging"
    ],
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

But I did not understand how to manage the javascript part, can someone explain it to me ?

My calc.bat's manifest.json :

```
{
    "name": "application",
    "description": "Lauching my app",
    "path": "C:\\Users\\root\\Documents\\calc.bat",
    "type": "stdio",
    "allowed_origins": [
        "chrome-extension://blfgmcilkaooeokpomhcpnfnhppjklcb"
    ]
}
```

Calc.bat is simply: `@echo off & start calc.exe`

Thanks in advance. If my question is not clear enough, tell me, I'll modify it.

Comment: If you have configured all correctly, you can add a content script to run on the url you want, make the content script send message to background script, and make background script send the native message to start the application.

Comment: thanks both of you Patrick and juvian. Patrick, yes I added previously the correct registry key to 
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.google.chrome.calc" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "mypath\\" /f

Juvian, can you be a bit more precise please ? I didn't understant perfectly the principle of Native Messaging. Can you maybe give me an example please ? Even looking on stackoverflow didn't helped me.

Comment: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging/

Comment: Thanks for your help @juvian :) But now the problem is that when I add `"matches": [
    "<all_urls>"
    ],`, and I reload, my extension generates an error : "Unrecognized manifest key 'matches'." And if I put it in the example.echo-win I have nothing, no error but the calc doesn't display. Is this happening because it's an app ?

Comment: There is no matches key on manifest, you need a content script: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: Ok @juvian, I passed last days by trying to make an extension ( with the help of the chrome.example. ) but it doesn't work as I expected. There is no change for both manifest.json upside. The difference is the key `REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\calc" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Users\root\Desktop\calc\manifest.json" /f` and the **background.js** : `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
  chrome.runtime.connectNative('calc');
})
` 
I did a picture, may it help you to help me :) [link](https://lut.im/tFSQKeJcAg/6TcYsLuThbr3uaiv.png)

Comment: You should check if it is giving any errors on background page

Comment: OK @juvian, so I run my background.js in the console's developer tool of my extension and I have a grey message : undefined. I don't realy understand because even if I change the `chrome.runtime.connectNative('calc'); ` to `chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage('calc');` the answer is the same...

Comment: can you upload it somewhere?

Comment: @juvian here is the link to my .zip : [mediafire](https://www.mediafire.com/file/pcsgd7u9hlfp82v/stackOv_ext.zip) **Extension** is the main file and **calc** the one with the batch file.
thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn´t get yours to work but the example I linked worked perfectly so started editing that one and ended up with this :

- Download [sample host](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/nativeMessaging/host.zip)
- Edit native-messaging-example-host.bat and replace with :

  @echo off

  calc.exe
- Run install_host.bat
- Make a folder called app on same directory as host folder
- Create 3 files : background.js, main.js, manifest.json

The content is:

**background.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
    if (message.action == "open app") {
        chrome.runtime.connectNative("com.google.chrome.example.echo");
    }
});
```

**main.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "open app"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

**manifest.json:**

```
    {
      // Extension ID: knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik
      "key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDcBHwzDvyBQ6bDppkIs9MP4ksKqCMyXQ/A52JivHZKh4YO/9vJsT3oaYhSpDCE9RPocOEQvwsHsFReW2nUEc6OLLyoCFFxIb7KkLGsmfakkut/fFdNJYh0xOTbSN8YvLWcqph09XAY2Y/f0AL7vfO1cuCqtkMt8hFrBGWxDdf9CQIDAQAB",
      "name": "Native Messaging Example",
      "version": "1.0",
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "description": "Send a message to a native application.",
      "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["main.js"],
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
      }],
      "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
      },
      "permissions": [
        "nativeMessaging"
      ]
    }
```

Finally, install the extension. This one in particular will open calc.exe every time you open/load a page, which can be easily changed with matches.

Another thing to note is that without the key in the manifest, it does not seem to work.

Comment: Can I call you " My lord " ? thanks a lot, now everything is clearer ! And I works perfectly !

Comment: Well it was definitely interesting to know that these things can be done with an extension :)